# Building android source code error

Tags: compiler-errors, makefile, android-source, building

When i try to building android source code using command make -j4 , i get error :

```
*** Done with the cleaning, now starting the real build.
Checking build tools versions...
build/core/base_rules.mk:130: 
*** Android/android-ndk-r8d/sources//android/cpufeatures:
MODULE.TARGET.STATIC_LIBRARIES.cpufeatures already defined by Android/android-ndk-r8d/sources/android/cpufeatures。stoped。
```

What is that meaning ,what is the problem ?

Comment: rm -fr out/ then make again is a simple fix.

Comment: thank you,i try, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

This might be a long guess, but can you check you don't have that same module there twice?

```
find . |grep cpufeatures
```

might give you the answer. The check done in that area is to verify each module is unique, if you have the same module in 2 places (say a copy error for example), then it would fail in this stage.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you do not have the NDK or SDK tarballs opened in the same directory as the AOSP, which already has its own ndk and sdk directories. This mistake caused the same problem for me as reported by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It turned out to be because I put NDK in the AOSP directory. One of AOSP's build script tried to do a directory travelsal and included some NDK's config files. After I moved out NDK, problem disappeared.